# How to get the MPMediaItem (audiobook) individual chapters

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery

I know I can get all the audiobooks from the iPod library with:

```
   MPMediaPropertyPredicate *abPredicate =
    [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:MPMediaTypeAudioBook] 
                                     forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType];

    MPMediaQuery *abQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
    [abQuery addFilterPredicate:abPredicate];
    [abQuery setGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingAlbum];
    NSArray *books = [abQuery collections];
```

And I can get the parts/files for each book by using this:

```
 [book items];
```

What I cant figure out is how to get the separate chapters that make up each part.

I know you can see this in the iPod application by tapping the "track" button in the upper right corner while playing a book. This flips the player around and shows the list of chapters.

Is apple using a private API to get this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 3):

To get the individual chapters you need to create an `AVAsset` from the `MPMediaItem`'s AssetURL property.

```
NSURL *assetURL = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil];
NSArray *locales = [asset availableChapterLocales];
NSArray *chapters = [asset chapterMetadataGroupsWithTitleLocale:locale containingItemsWithCommonKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:AVMetadataCommonKeyArtwork]];
```

Get the url and create the asset, check the available locales for the chapter, and get the chapters from the asset. The result is an array of `AVTimedMetadataGroup`s that each contain a `CMTimeRange` and an array of `AVMetadataItem`s. Each `AVMetadataItem` holds a piece of metadata (e.g. chapter title, chapter artwork).

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAsset/chapterMetadataGroupsWithTitleLocale%3acontainingItemsWithCommonKeys%3a) the only supported key is the `AVMetadataCommonKeyArtwork`.