# Is it possible to get video-related meta info for an MPMediaItem?

Tags: ios, video, properties, metadata, mpmediaitem

I'm doing some work with MPMediaItems, and specifically I'm trying to get a list of the videos on a user's device.  Now, videos from iTunes will be locked so they can't be played from a third-party app, but user-added videos like home movies are playable, and even those from iTunes can have their meta information queried and displayed.

But here's where I'm getting tripped up: I can't seem to find any video-specific meta info for these files?

The [MPMediaItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/General_Media_Item_Property_Keys) class reference has a long list of properties that you can access, but they're mostly audio-specific.  Things like `MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle` or `MPMediaItemPropertyComposer`.  There's even a section for Podcast-specific properties, but I can't seem to find anything like "Season Number" or "Episode Number" or "Show Title".  This information is obviously stored by iTunes, and it's displayed by the in-house Videos app, but I can't find any way to get it myself.

These are the only fields I can find in the class reference:

`NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID ;            // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumPersistentID ;       // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyArtistPersistentID ;      // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtistPersistentID ; // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyGenrePersistentID ;       // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyComposerPersistentID ;    // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyPodcastPersistentID ;     // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType ;               // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyTitle ;                   // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle ;              // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyArtist ;                  // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist ;             // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyGenre ;                   // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyComposer ;                // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackCount;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyDiscNumber;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyDiscCount;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyLyrics;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyIsCompilation ;           // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyReleaseDate;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyBeatsPerMinute;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyComments;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem ;              // filterable`

I'm fairly confident that this information isn't available through the MPMediaItemProperties values, but can it be accessed in any other way?  Is there even a round-about method for accessing this information, something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983272/get-date-when-mpmediaitem-was-added-to-itunes-library) which I don't completely understand but which seems promising, or is it completely impossible for a developer to see what show/season a video is from?

**EDIT:**  This became especially important recently, because the most recent version of iTunes now no longer even presents those audio-specific fields (like "Album" or "Artist") when editing video files.  Going to "Get Info" on a video file in iTunes now *only* shows the video-specific fields, meaning that videos input after this update now seem to be completely un-sortable in a third-party app.

...unless someone has an idea?

**EDIT 2:**  In my research I've come across the `AVMetadataItem` class, which I'd never heard of before, and specifically the `AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKey` options ([class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_iTunesMetadataConstants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/iTunes_Metadata)).  They don't seem to include Show, Season, or Episode info, but they do have some video-specific fields like `AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyDirector`.  Is there some other use of this class, or some other video-related class like [AVAsset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10670696/1418688), that might have a roundabout access to the info I'm looking for?

**EDIT 3:** Got my hopes up when I found the [iTunes Library Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/iTunesLibrary/Reference/iTunesLibraryFrameworkReference/), which includes a `ITLibMediaItemVideoInfo` class that is EXACTLY what I'm looking for.  However, it seems to be Mac-only, and I need it on iOS...  Any chance someone has a work-around to access this info on iOS?

Comment: Did you check to see if iTunes doesn't already store the Episode or Season number in one of those existing fields already? (i.e. MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber)

Comment: @Oren Yeah, they're all blank for a video file.

Comment: At least AlbumTitle, Artist, AlbumArtist, AlbumTrackNumber, and Composer are blank.  I didn't check every single one, but I don't see them storing Show Name in the Lyrics field, you know?

Comment: Why would that be in Lyrics? If there's any info on the id3 tags I would expect MPMediaItemPropertyTitle would be populated. Nothing there for you either?

Comment: @Oren It wouldn't be in Lyrics, my point was that I've checked all the fields where it was likely to be, and I ignored the fields (like Lyrics) where they obviously wouldn't be putting it.  MPMediaItemPropertyTitle has data, but that's one of the audio-and-video fields.  I'm looking for the fields that pertain only to video files, like Show Name, Season Number, etc.

Comment: Why the downvote?  It's a specific question, clearly stated, with my research detailed and updated as I've continued working on it.

Comment: You're not really responding to comments anymore, so I'll leave you with this link. Best of luck: https://code.google.com/p/subler/source/browse/trunk/mp4v2+wrapper/MP42AVFImporter.m?r=972

Comment: @Drakes What do you mean? I'm still responding to comments, this is the first one you've left...

Comment: @Nerrolken Hello, oh, I was wondering if you had any luck with source I provided in my answer, or the media keys, or should I keep digging? :)

Comment: @Drakes Awesome, thanks!  I didn't see that you'd answered.  I'll check out this option ASAP!

Answer (score 0):

This may help you with exactly what are you looking for: [https://code.google.com/p/subler/source/browse/trunk/mp4v2+wrapper/MP42AVFImporter.m](https://code.google.com/p/subler/source/browse/trunk/mp4v2+wrapper/MP42AVFImporter.m?r=972)

Here is a highlight of the relevant section you may be interested in related to `AVMetadataKeySpaceiTunes`:

```
...
@"Description",         @"desc",
@"Long Description",    @"ldes",
@"Media Kind",          @"stik",
@"TV Show",             @"tvsh",
@"TV Episode #",        @"tves",
@"TV Network",          @"tvnn",
@"TV Episode ID",       @"tven",
@"TV Season",           @"tvsn",
@"HD Video",            @"hdvd",
@"Gapless",             @"pgap",
@"Sort Name",           @"sonm",
@"Sort Artist",         @"soar",
@"Sort Album Artist",   @"soaa",
@"Sort Album",          @"soal",
@"Sort Composer",       @"soco",
@"Sort TV Show",        @"sosn",
@"Category",            @"catg",
@"iTunes U",            @"itnu",
@"Purchase Date",       @"purd",
...
```

Comment: I've been wrestling with several personal tragedies, so I apologize for not responding about this sooner.  But I'm getting back to this project now, and I appreciate your answer!  However, unless I'm reading this wrong, the link you provided doesn't actually get the info requested?  The code you quoted simply sets `@"TV Episode #"` to a placeholder string, while other properties like `@"Album"` get set to things like `AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyAlbum`. Where does it actually *find* the episode number, etc?